# Zend Framework 2.0.2 YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube-api, zend-framework2

### Question

I cant seem to find any YouTube API documents on the new Zend Framework 2.0.2. Is there any external or extra downloads I need to do? All the tutorials are based on older versions of Zend!

Or should I just download an older version of Zend?

---

### Answer

I'm giving this answer for anyone else that may need it in the future.

You will have to download Zend Framework 1.7.7. As the YouTube API uses the Gdata folder. On my research this is the only version that will support the YouTube API.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GData API is available in ZF2, you just need to install the package that contains it.

You can find a list of available packages [here](http://packages.zendframework.com).

If you are already using Composer for ZF2, simply add `"zendframework/zendgdata": "2.0.*"` to the list of pacakges in the `require` section and then run `php composer.phar update` to fetch the GData package and you can now begin using the GData classes.

If you aren't using Composer, here is how you can obtain the GData\YouTube library.

From a new directory, install Composer:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Note: If you don't have cURL, just download the installer from the above URL and run `php installer`

Now that Composer is installed create a `composer.json` file with the following contents:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendgdata": "2.0.*"
    }
}
```

By adding the `zendframework/zendgdata` package to the `require` list, composer will download and install this package along with ZF2.

Now run the install:

```
php composer.phar install
```

You now have a copy of Zend Framework 2 and the GData package in the newly created `vendor` directory.

To test it, create test.php in the same directory as `composer.json` that looks like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$youtube = new ZendGData\YouTube();

var_dump($youtube);
```

The usage of the GData YouTube APIs in ZF2 are similar to in ZF1, but if you look in the `vendor/zendframework/zendgdata/tests/ZendGData/` directory, you can see a number of tests which you can use as examples for getting started with the various ZF2 YouTube classes.

Hope that helps.